# Print grid bug with absolute position

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

When printing a grid using css to hide other elements on the page, and the grid overflows the page, it duplicates rows on page break, and also squishes some rows. See screenshot.

Here is a code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/print-ag-grid-absolute-simpler-ywn2qs?file=/src/App.vue

If the grid width is explicitly set to 670px for 8.5x11 inch paper, then it prints fine. But that is not a reasonable assumption to make for users.

How can this problem be prevented? Please let me know if I should frame the problem differently?

[image]